# É preciso utilizar as bibliotecas AppCompat e Support Design quando a API mínima é 21?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android

Recentemente atualizei um aplicativo que estou desenvolvendo para utilizar de API mínima a 21 (Lollipop), antes estava na 19 (KitKat).

No caso da KitKat eu precisava usar a AppCompat e o Support Design para usufruir do DrawerLayout, CoordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton, etc, só que no Lollipop alguns desses controles são suportados nativamente.

A dúvida é: eu preciso continuar referenciando a AppCompat e o Support Design? E se sim, quais partes das libs?

Acredito que provavelmente terei que adaptar o código para essas alterações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Não**, se usar apenas as funcionalidades existentes no(até) Loolipop.

**Sim**, se quiser utilizar novas funcionalidades e novos métodos disponibilizados nas versões após o Loolipop.

Answer (score 1):

Se sua **API** mínima agora é a 21, você não vai mais precisar utilizar essas bibliotecas de suporte. Mesmo.

Elas servem para oferecer compatibilidade para dispositivos `pré-loolipop` (**API 21**), isto é, para dispositivos com API entre 21 e 9, pois esta é a mínima que a biblioteca pode suportar.